# ELDoc and company-tern are not working properly in JS2-mode (.js buffer in node) and Javascript, in Emacs

Tags: company-mode, javascript, js2-mode, eldoc, tern

In my Emacs configuration for JavaScript/ JS2-mode, specifically **.js buffer in node**:

(1) **company-tern and  ELDoc are NOT working properly**.

For eg. when I type 'console.l', 'log' does not pop up, rather 'let' alone pops up

(2) When opening the buffer, a message pop ups, ***"There is no ELDoc support in this buffer"***

**My key Emacs configurations**, for this:

**Company:**

```
(use-package company
  :ensure t
  :config (global-company-mode t)
  (progn
    (setq company-idle-delay 0)
    (setq company-minimum-prefix-length 1)
    (setq company-etags-everywhere '(html-mode web-mode js-mode js2-mode nxml-mode))
```

**tern:**

```
(use-package tern
  :ensure t
  :config
  (progn
    (autoload 'tern-mode "tern.el" nil t)
    (add-hook 'js-mode-hook (lambda () (tern-mode t)))
    (add-hook 'js2-mode-hook (lambda () (tern-mode t)))))
```

**company-tern:**

```
(use-package company-tern   
  :ensure t   
  :config   
    (with-eval-after-load 'company 'tern    
      '(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-tern)))
```

**ELDoc:**

```
(global-eldoc-mode 1)
(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook 'eldoc-mode)
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook 'eldoc-mode)
```

**Can some one help me to sort out what I am doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

### ElDoc

When `eldoc-mode` is enabled it checks whether `eldoc-documentation-function` is defined in current buffer. If not - it messages "*There is no ElDoc support in this buffer*" and exits.
Neither of these modes supports `ElDoc`, i.e. doesn't implement `eldoc-documentation-function`.

### Company

When new characters are typed, `company` after each command checks for a possibility to complete it.
If `company` triggers a completion process, it loops over each member of `company-backends` list:

```el
(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-tern)
```

So completion depends on which *company backend* first is able to return some completion.
<sub>**BTW, `add-to-list` is quoted in your setup.**</sub>

That `company` looping over all backends can be avoided:

<kbd>`M-x company-tern`</kbd> calls only `tern` backend at point.(try it first)

**Or**, instead of adding `company-tern` to `company-backends` list, it can be assigned to a variable:
`company-backend` (notice there's no "**s**" in the end). This variable is provided by `company` for "manual override" cases, it means - use only one this backend.
It's a buffer local variable, so it should be assigned inside javascript mode hooks:

```el
(setq company-backend company-tern)
```

Comment: Thanks **Alexandr Karbivnichiy**: (1) I agree with your answer that there is **no ELDoc** support for `company-tern`. (2) Re: **company**, I had to _quote_ `add-to-list` to get pop up of 'console' when typing **c**. And, `(setq company-backend company-term)` idea did not work for me.

Comment: So inside of a Javascript buffer, what is the value of ‘company-backends’?